# resizing <body> to create a viewport sized background image

Tags: html, css

I was looking at path.com today and liked their implementation of a dynamically sized cover photo.  If you check it out you will see that it sizes nicely no matter your screen size.

I looked a little more into it and noticed the background image is attached to the body tag.  I also noticed the body appears to get its size from the form element inside it, meaning the body itself it actually shorter than the total page.

Does anyone know how they accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also, the body height is set to 100% of the viewport.

Comment: I think this explains it, is it setting both HTML and BODY height to 100% that accomplishes this?

Comment: Yes, if you open the web developer tools and click on `body` you'll notice it is sized as tall as the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for this part:

```
body.home {
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: does that explain how the body changes with the viewport, even though the content (namely the 'about' div) extends beyond it?

Comment: as @beautifulcoder says, the body height is also set to 100% of the viewport